# Learning Swift - inout functions - Why do they modify the global variable values?

Tags: javascript, swift

I'm coming from a Javascript background and I'm looking for some clarity on inout with Swift.

In Javascript, a function's parameter only exists within the scope of that function. So for instance I could do this without a problem.

```
function greet(name) {
 name = "randomDude";
 return name
}

greet("Barry");
```

This works because the parameter name only exists within the scope of the greet function. So I can change the value of name.

However, in Swift, I cannot do this:

```
func greet(name: String) {
   name = "Ardvark"
   print(name)
}

greet(name: "Drew")
```

The solution would be to change it to an 'inout' function, which can only take a variable, i.e.:

```
func greet(name: inout String) {
       name = "Ardvark"
       print(name)
    }

var name = "Drew"    
greet(name: name)
```

However, when I do this, it actually CHANGES the value of var name. Meaning the inout function doesn't modify only the value of the PARAMETER within the scope of the function, but modifies the global variable.

Is this just something I have to accept? Is there a reason it modifies the global variable? How would you modify only the variable 'name' inside the function greet?

Thanks

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. In the second code example the variable "name" also only exists in the scope of the greet function. Why would that not work? You cannot modify the parameter, because they are constants by default, but why would you want to?

Comment: @Lupinity Parameters are immutable in Swift 3. You can't assign a new value to `name` inside the function.

Comment: @rmaddy: yes, but I don't see the point of assigning a value there at all?

Comment: @Lupinity There isn't really. The OP is just doing that as an example for comparison sake with Javascript.

Comment: Yes I am just trying to understand at a lower level. For instance, in Javascript, you can mutate the parameter value because it simply exists as a variable inside the new execution context of the greet scope. If that is the case in Swift, then how come it changes the GLOBAL value when you mutate it inside the function?

Comment: Up voting daddy's answer, but in case your Java background translates this, consider that Swift 3.0 only has "by val (read-only)" or "by ref". The former is "let" and the latter is "inout". If you want a "by val (read-write)", you need to declare a new local function variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason the 2nd block of code (1st Swift example) prevents you from changing the value of `name` is because in Swift 3, all parameters are constants. In other words they are essentially all declared with `let`.

Imagine your first Swift example as:

```
func greet(let name: String) {
   name = "Ardvark"
   print(name)
}
```

Obviously you don't really put `let` there but that will help you remember that parameters are immutable. This prevents you from changing the value by mistake. If you want to change it just inside the function, use a new variable:

```
func greet(name: String) {
   let anotherName = "Ardvark"
   print(anotherName)
}
```

Using `inout` changes the parameter by "removing the let" and allowing you to change the original variable used when calling the function.

> How would you modify only the variable 'name' inside the function greet?

You don't in Swift 3. The parameter is immutable. Assign it to a new variable inside the function.

Comment: Also doesn't `inout` mean that the modifications made are reflected back in the calling environment? It seems like an extreme solution to the problem of unmodifiable parameters ...

Comment: @Pointy Yes, that's why I stated in my last line that `inout` allows you to change the original value. By original value I mean the variable passed to the function.

Comment: Right, but I meant that because `inout` means what it's pretty much always meant in programming languages, if all you want to do is have a variable initialized to the value of a parameter, you'd probably just declare a `var` variable and initialize it. (Note that I'm not a Swift programmer :)

Comment: Okay I now understand that parameters in Swift are constants and not variables, to make it harder to accidentally change a value. However, I don't understand why removing the constant let by using an 'inout', thereby changing the variable IN THE SCOPE OF THE FUNCTION, changes the global variable. Does this mean that parameters are referring to the global namespace and not a new variable created in the scope of the function?

Comment: `inout` is specifically meant to be used when you want to pass an updated value back to the variable used to call the function. Never use `inout` unless that is what you specifically want to do. Swift doesn't support Javascript's model. The closest you get is to use a new variable inside the function like I show in my answer.

Comment: The Swift language documentation makes this somewhat confusing, in my opinion, especially for those not otherwise familiar with the terminology "in-out parameter".

Answer (score 2):

In the `func greet(name: String) {}` function `name` is a constant, actually it looks like `func greet(let name: String) {}` so you can't modify it. Let add a new variable and assign value of `name` to it:

```
func greet(name: String) {
    var newName = name
    newName = "Ardvark"
    print(newName)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just read some of the Swift docs. Came to two conclusions.

(1) By default, parameters in Swift are CONSTANTS, so it's as if there is a let keyword before the parameter. Meaning inside the function, the parameter value cannot be changed, or an error will be thrown.

(2) Changing your function to an 'inout' function changes things. First off, it removes the 'let' constraint. Secondly, when you pass in an argument to the inout parameter, it is known as copy-in, copy-out. The argument's value is copied in memory, passed through the function, modified in the function, and the new value is assigned to the original variable that was passed as an argument.

These are two distinct types of functions if you think about it. In other words, there is no functionality like in Javascript where you can simply modify the parameter's value inside the scope of the function ONLY.

Because:

The parameter is either a CONSTANT (by default),

OR...

You are using an inout function, in which case, the parameter is a variable as opposed to a constant, but that parameter only exists for the purpose of 'transferring' an argument's original value into a function where it can be modified, and then spit back out as a new value to the original variable placeholder in memory.

In other words... There is no way (that I know of) in Swift to only modify a parameter's value INSIDE the scope of it's function. You are either prohibited from doing so by default because the parameter is a constant, or you are using an inout function, which isn't modifying the parameter's value inside the function only... It is modifying the GLOBAL namespace's value.